# How to change specific words' font color of .pptx file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

```
searchInput = "chapter"
try:
    prs = Presentation("e:/test3/ch7.pptx")
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                shape.text = shape.text.lower()
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if searchInput in run.text:
                            print(run.text)
                            #run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 255)


except PermissionError:
    pass
prs.save("e:/test3/ch7_modified1.pptx")
```

Now, I can check whether this "ch7.pptx" file contains specific words I want to find.

If I print(run.text), It print out

```
chapter 7:  synchronization examples
chapter 7: synchronization examples
end of chapter 7
```

So, I can see there are several words "chapter". 
But, I want to change the color of "chapter" to Yellow in my "ch7.pptx", then I want to save to "ch7_modified.pptx"

I keep tying to find how to change the color but it does not work properly. Please, Give me some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that a given word will begin and end in a single run; any given word may be split across multiple runs and its runs may contain prior and trailing text. PowerPoint will split runs wherever it pleases, perhaps to highlight a misspelled word or just if you pause in typing or go in to fix a typo or something.

The only thing that can be said for sure about a run is that all the characters it contains share the same character formatting.

So to do what you want requires a substantially more sophisticated algorithm and some low-level features `python-pptx` doesn't have yet.

The general approach would be something like this:

- find a paragraph that contains the search word
- from that paragraph, find the subsequence of runs that contain that word. In general this is a sequence (list) and can include text before the word starts and after it ends.
- divide the first of these runs into two at the word start (unless it starts on an even run boundary)
- break the last of these runs into two at the word end (unless it ends on an even run boundary)
- set the formatting of all the (middle) runs that contain all or part of the word to your desired settings

There is currently no API support for the run-splitting bit and it would require working with the underlying XML objects in `python-pptx` which is something of an advanced topic. If you want to pursue that, searching Google on "python-pptx workaround function" will give you a place to start.